# SQL find local date and time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am facing the date and time issue in my sql server 2012 and web form. it is taking the server date and time. how i can get client location date and time. what i have done so far is.

```
Declare @TodayDate datetime
Set @TodayDate = (SELECT DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), GETDATE()))
```

it is giving me correct date only but not time. how to get both date and time.

In my webform i try this code, i got it from one forum again. Until now am not try it. Please help me to find correct solution for this.

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime localDate = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Well, if you want to store the client date and time in the database, you need to pass it from the client to the server. Just take `DateTime.Now` and pass it as parameter to your query.

Comment: DateTime.Now i tried in asp.net c# but not correct date and time.

Comment: Well, it will give you the time on the server running the code behind. Your C# code can not access client data as it doesn't run on the client. If you want the time on the visitors PC you need to add client side code (Javascript) that sends that information to the server.

Comment: @thorsten i will try what you suggest. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible from server to locate user place. DateTime.Now show you server data not users date. You have to get user time through javascript. You can store utc time in Database. After that convert utc time to user time through javascript.